# Tell Django Compressor to ignore certain directories when compiling

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

I use [`django-compressor`](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to compile and minify my static assets.  I have some templates from Angular or from other Django libraries that ultimately get thrown into my `staticfiles` directory that I don't want `django_compressor` compressing.  In fact, when it runs over them currently, it throws a lot of noisy errors:

```
Error parsing template /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suit/templates/admin/filer/image/change_form.html: 'filermedia' is not a valid tag library: Template library filermedia not found, tried django.templatetags.filermedia,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.filermedia,django_select2.templatetags.filermedia, <...>
Invalid template /app/staticfiles/profile-page/bower_components/angular-strap/src/datepicker/datepicker.tpl.html: Could not parse the remainder: '$iconLeft' from '$iconLeft'
```

Is there any way to tell `django-compressor` to ignore certain directories/files?

Comment: maybe you can define custom filters to ignore certain files ?

Answer (score 0):

When using Django Compressor's compress management command, you don't have the option of excluding some static files or templates form being compressed. It is not provided as an out of the box solution.

However if you make a templatetag that calls a class inheriting from CompressorNode, you can implement is_offline_compression_enabled() in that class to disable offline compression for all codes using that template tag.